# Create django join with fields that don't have same name

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to turn the following SQL statement into a normal Django query.

```
SELECT * FROM table w JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM student_class WHERE class_id=8) AS s 
ON s.student_id=w.id;
```

I want to only look at the rows in student_class that match on a specific value (here `class_id=8`) and then join those results by matching `s.student_id` with `w.id`.

It seems like I should be able to do something using the `.filter()` and some double underscores like .`filter(student_class__class_id=8)` but I can't get this working.

Comment: You are not actually using the [reserved wor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `table` as table name, are you? Edit your question with a proper name please. And what do you want to return? All columns? Or just columns of `table`?

Comment: It would help us if you posted the relevant models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should help to untangle your twisted statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table w
JOIN   student_class s ON s.student_id = w.id
WHERE  s.class_id = 8;
```

Replace `table` with a proper name.
If the tables have defined relationships, this Django syntax should work:

```
Table.objects.filter(student_class__class_id=8)
```

[Per Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#s-lookups-that-span-relationships)

> Lookups that span relationships
>
> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
> in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind
> the scenes. To span a relationship, just use **the field name of related
> fields across models, separated by double underscores**, until you get
> to the field you want.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Okay, I see that that gives me the same results for the main query. But I'm still having trouble turning this into a django request. 
I assume this means it'd be something like `Student_Class.objects.filter(<insert something connecting w.id to student_id).filter(class_id=8)`. But I'm still not clear how to express the connection in django betwee w.id and s.student_id.

Comment: @akajb: Added Django syntax.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: with regard to SQL query, the one SO posted and what you suggested are basically same. I think what SO suggested could be faster because you limit the number of rows from student_class to be joined. am I correct? Your Django query is perfect

Comment: @akajb to connect, just use the double underscore of the foreign key - and then refer to the column (property) of the linked model you want. So `FKName__name_of_column_in_linked_model=3`

Comment: I played around with this a lot more, and from what I can tell, Django won't find the relationship if you don't match the foreign key from one table to be the foreign key to a second table (not the table requesting). Which I don't think I conveyed clearly when I tried to change tables name for my example above. But, I figured out a different table structure that allowed it to point how Django wants it to, and doesn't prevent what I need captured.

Comment: Anyway, I approved the answer, because it is correct for what was being shown.